# Why does writing a file to an NFS share send a COMMIT operation to the NFS server?

Tags: linux, nfs

I have a Debian squeeze (2.6.32-5-amd64) which is at the same time a NFS4 server and client (it mounts itself through NFS4). The local directory that leads directly to disk is `/nfs4exports/mydir`, whereas `/nfs4mounts/mydir` is the same thing mounted through NFS, using the machine's external IP address. Here is the line from `fstab`:

```
192.168.1.75:/mydir   /nfs4mounts/mydir      nfs4    soft  0 0
```

I have an application that writes many small files. If I write directly to `/nfs4exports/mydir`, it writes thousands of files per second; but if I write to `/nfs4mounts/mydir`, it writes 4 files per second or so. I can greatly increase speed if I add `async` to `/etc/exports`. (Writing a single large file to the NFS-mounted directory goes at more than 100 MB/s.)

I examine the server statistics and I see that whenever a file is written, it is "committed" (this also happens with NFSv3):

```
root@debianvboxtest:~# mount -t nfs4 192.168.1.75:/mydir /mnt
root@debianvboxtest:~# nfsstat|grep -A 2 'nfs v4 operations'
Server nfs v4 operations:
op0-unused   op1-unused   op2-future   access       close        commit       
0         0% 0         0% 0         0% 10        4% 1         0% 1         0% 
root@debianvboxtest:~# echo 'hello' >/mnt/test1056
root@debianvboxtest:~# nfsstat|grep -A 2 'nfs v4 operations'
Server nfs v4 operations:
op0-unused   op1-unused   op2-future   access       close        commit       
0         0% 0         0% 0         0% 11        4% 2         0% 2         0%
```

Now in [the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3530#page-144), I read this:

> The COMMIT operation is similar in operation and semantics to the
> POSIX fsync(2) system call that synchronizes a file's state with the
> disk (file data and metadata is flushed to disk or stable storage).
> COMMIT performs the same operation for a client, flushing any
> unsynchronized data and metadata on the server to the server's disk or
> stable storage for the specified file.

I don't understand why the client commits. I don't think that the "echo" shell built-in command runs `fsync`; if `echo` wrote to a local file and then the machine went down, the file might be lost. In contrast, the NFS client appears to be sending a COMMIT upon completion of the `echo`. Why?

I am reluctant to use the [`async` NFS server option](http://nfs.sourceforge.net/nfs-howto/ar01s05.html#sync_versus_async), because it would apparently ignore COMMIT. I feel as if I had a local filesystem and I had to choose between syncing every file upon close and ignoring `fsync` altogether. What have I understood wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because this is how NFS works, and is exactly how it should work since it's a synchronous protocol. What you need to make sure is that the file system that is exported is backed by LUNs that have NVRAM/BBWC protection and properly handle fsync() - ie ignore that, and mask SCSI FUA flags and SCSI_CACHE_SYNCHRONIZE commands. Also make sure that the file system has no barriers enabled if it's backed by BBWC/NVRAM.

This way NFS keeps it's synchronous semantics and is equivalent to running fsync() after every write, but you get the performance of running asynchronously.

Comment: This extract from https://blogs.oracle.com/roch/entry/nfs_and_zfs_a_fine also explains the rationale behind this behaviour: "With local filesystems, a system crash is plainly obvious to users and requires applications to be restarted. With NFS, a server crash in not obvious to users of the service (the only sign being a lengthy pause), and applications are not notified. The fact that files or parts of files may go missing in the absence of errors can be considered as plain corruption of the client's side view."